# Pigeon principle question: Nine points in a diamond

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

A diamond (a parallelogram with equal sides) is given, and its sides are 2 cm long. The sharp angels are 60 degrees. If there are nine points **inside** the diamond, prove that there must be two of them so that the distance between them is at most 1 cm.

Ideas where to start from?

Comment: Nine points and the pigeonhole principle suggests trying to find 8 "pigeonholes" for nine points.

Comment: Your diamond is a two-dimensional figure, I think?

Comment: I believe that “a parallelogram with equal sides” is usually called a “rhombus”.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Split the diamond into eight congruent equilateral triangles. The triangles are your pigeon holes.

Comment: The diamond may be a regular tetrahedron of side $2$.

Comment: @André, that possibility did not occur to me. Well spotted!  But in that case there would be no need to specify the acute angle? I'm sticking to the interpretation: a diamond = a parallelogram with equal sides, but let's wait for the OP to comment.

Comment: @André, thanks for the thought, but it is two-dimensional diamond.Therefore, this hint will do the job.